# Retrieve data with ajax from a web page which need authentication

Tags: php, ajax

I need to retrieve data from a webpage which need authentication. if I don't login it will send restricted access responce. how can I login to that page with PHP and after that send my param's to that page and retrieve data?
if I totally mistaking in my scenario what is the proper method for doing this? 
I have to add this, the second page is a jsp page on another server.

Best Regards.

Comment: Are those 2 pages in same server?

Comment: create a users , and then call login from while loading the page , then authenticate the user , if yes then show the page else return false

Comment: @aivar no :D the second page is a JSP page in another server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use curl.
At your php-script, which you used for your ajax request, you could open the login page. Than check which parameters does the login page needs and post the data to the login page with another curl request.
After that, you should be logged in and could retrieve the wanted data with another last curl request.
Make sure to setup the cookie usage, so the page can identify your request with the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions like:

```
authentication.php
<?php
session_start();
$sessionUserId = $_SESSION['userid'];

if(empty($sessionUserId))
{
   //send the user to the login page
   header("location:login.php");  // or any other page
}
?>
```

then in your php which you will call with ajax, include it in the first line of the page:

```
include_once("authentication.php");
```

So, it will check if session exists, it will continue execution or it will ask user for loging in.

**Note:** `$_SESSION['userid']` takes its value after valid login.

Comment: the problem is that that page isn't created by me and it is a jsp page located in another host.